# Adding lambda functions with the same operator in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a rather lengthy equation that I need to integrate over using scipy.integrate.quad and was wondering if there is a way to add lambda functions to each other. What I have in mind is something like this

```
y = lambda u: u**(-2) + 8
x = lambda u: numpy.exp(-u)
f = y + x
int = scipy.integrate.quad(f, 0, numpy.inf)
```

The equations that I am really using are far more complicated than I am hinting at here, so for readability it would be useful to break up the equation into smaller, more manageable parts.

Is there a way to do with with lambda functions? Or perhaps another way which does not even require lambda functions but will give the same output?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `scipy.integrate.quad`, but `f = lambda u: y(u) + x(u)` would be a way to add the two functions together.

Comment: Aside: why are you using `lambda` at all if you're going to give your functions a name immediately anyway?

Comment: Honestly I am using lambda because I don't know any other options with my very limited python experience, which is why I added the last part to the question.

Comment: As a little vocabulary tip (I think), do you mean "functions with the same parameters" or "signature"?

Comment: Feel free to edit my question if you think it will make it more findable for other users.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Python, you'll normally only use a lambda for very short, simple functions that easily fit inside the line that's creating them. (Some languages have other opinions.)

As @DSM hinted in their comment, lambdas are essentially a shortcut to creating functions when it's not worth giving them a name.

If you're doing more complex things, or if you need to give the code a name for later reference, a lambda expression won't be much of a shortcut for you -- instead, you might as well `def`ine a plain old function.

So instead of assigning the lambda expression to a variable:

```
y = lambda u: u**(-2) + 8
```

You can define that variable to be a function:

```
def y(u):
    return u**(-2) + 8
```

Which gives you room to explain a bit, or be more complex, or whatever you need to do:

```
def y(u):
    """
    Bloopinate the input

    u should be a positive integer for fastest results.
    """
    offset = 8
    bloop = u ** (-2)
    return bloop + offset
```

Functions and lambdas are both "callable", which means they're essentially interchangable as far as `scipy.integrate.quad()` is concerned.

To combine callables, you can use several different techniques.

```
def triple(x):
   return x * 3

def square(x):
   return x * x

def triple_square(x):
   return triple(square(x))

def triple_plus_square(x):
    return triple(x) + square(x)

def triple_plus_square_with_explaining_variables(x):
    tripled = triple(x)
    squared = square(x)
    return tripled + squared
```

There are more advanced options that I would only consider if it makes your code clearer (which it probably won't). For example, you can put the callables in a list:

```
 all_the_things_i_want_to_do = [triple, square]
```

Once they're in a list, you can use list-based operations to work on them (including applying them in turn to `reduce` the list down to a single value).

But if your code is like most code, regular functions that just call each other by name will be the simplest to write and easiest to read.

Comment: This is likely the solution to OP's real problem.

Comment: This is pythonic and testable. Lambda should be obviously correct. Like lowercasing a string or adding a constant. For numerical code in most cases it will be better to extract the functions . Also it wont encourage single name variables as we see above.

Answer (score 13):

There's no built-in functionality for that, but you can implement it quite easily (with some performance hit, of course):

```
import numpy

class Lambda:

    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Lambda(
            lambda *args, **kwds: self._func(*args, **kwds) + other._func(*args, **kwds))

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        return self._func(*args, **kwds)

y = Lambda(lambda u: u**(-2) + 8)
x = Lambda(lambda u: numpy.exp(-u))

print((x + y)(1))
```

Other operators can be added in a similar way.

Comment: This can be good for creating a full DSL, but be aware that there are a lot of little intricacies to deal with. You'll need to do some pretty thorough edge case testing to get it working smoothly. For most applications, it's probably not worth the trouble, which leaves you with RJHunter's solution. +1 for the Python way of overriding operators, though.

Answer (score 10):

With `sympy` you can do function operation like this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify, implemented_function
>>> from sympy.abc import u
>>> y = implemented_function('y', lambda u: u**(-2) + 8)
>>> x = implemented_function('x', lambda u: numpy.exp(-u))
>>> f = lambdify(u, y(u) + x(u))
>>> f(numpy.array([1,2,3]))
array([ 9.36787944,  8.13533528,  8.04978707])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use code below to rich same result with writing as **less code** as possible:

```
y = lambda u: u**(-2) + 8
x = lambda u: numpy.exp(-u)
f = lambda u, x=x, y=y: x(u) + y(u)
int = scipy.integrate.quad(f, 0, numpy.inf)
```

Answer (score 3):

As a functional programmer, I suggest generalizing the solutions to an [applicative combinator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2):

```
In [1]: def lift2(h, f, g): return lambda x: h(f(x), g(x))
In [2]: from operator import add
In [3]: from math import exp
In [4]: y = lambda u: u**(-2) + 8
In [5]: x = lambda u: exp(-u)
In [6]: f = lift2(add, y, x)
In [7]: [f(u) for u in range(1,5)]
Out[7]: [9.367879441171443, 8.385335283236612, 8.160898179478975, 8.080815638888733]
```

Using `lift2`, you can combine the output of two functions using arbitrary binary functions in a pointfree way. And most of the stuff in `operator` should probably be enough for typical mathematical combinations, avoiding having to write any lambdas.

In a similar fasion, you might want to define `lift1` and maybe `lift3`, too.